# Improve performance in sum across multiple rows for multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I have MySQL sub query to select multiple rows with 15 columns names,joining two tables one has 4,00,000 record another one has 9000 records.

In this filter using unique id in both tables,in where clause using date filter as between ..  and ... date column mostly having null value only.Added index for both table columns its reduced 28 sec to 17 sec ..

140 rows retrieving in this select statement..In this case sum across multiple rows for multiple fields took more time to retrieve data,.How to improve performance to this query?If any one has experience share it?

```
  SELECT A.xs_id ,
       A.unique_id ,
       sum(A.xs_type) AS TYPE ,
       sum(A.xs_item_type) AS item_type ,
       sum(A.xs_counterno) AS counterno ,
       r.Modified_date ,
       sum(A.sent) AS sent ,
       sum(A.sent_amt) AS amount ,
       (sum(sent_amt)+sum(rec_amt)) AS total
FROM xs_data A
JOIN r_data r ON (r.unique_id=A.uniqueid
                  AND summ_id =1
                  AND modified_date IS NOT NULL
                  WHERE date(modified_date) BETWEEN '2012-02-12' AND '2013-01-22')
GROUP BY date(modified_date),
         A.xs_id,
         A.unique_id;
```

Comment: Please post your query.

Comment: hi,i have added my query and its include also many columns ,only added few its include count (distinct ..) column fields also , only added sum fields..

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on modified_date, then the BETWEEN query can use it. Once you put a column into a function `DATE(modified_date)`, MySQL no longer uses the column's index, so it has to go through all the rows (that's called a full table scan).

It could be helpful to use

```
WHERE `modified_date` >= '2012-02-12 00:00:00'
  AND `modified_date` < '2013-01-23 00:00:00'
```

On the other hand [`EXPLAIN SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) will tell you more.

Comment: hi michal thank you and modified date column has 70 % null values only is there any problem in filtration?

Comment: It could be filtering as you have millions of rows. It could also be some temporary table created as you are joining large tables. Those are just guesses. Using EXPLAIN SELECT and maybe a bit of PROFILING can hint.

Comment: Hi michal i have done as you said its reduced 9 sec , but <= 2013-01-23 date records not retrieving in this select statement .any ideas to retrieve all results within date 12 to 23.

Comment: @Selva I don't know the type you are using for column `modified_date` I presumed timestamp. It could be date, so it would be `WHERE modified_date >= '2012-02-12' AND modified_date < '2013-01-23'`

Comment: your thought is right ..modified date column value includes date with time , time stamp is enough but as u mentioned before index will not work for the modified_date..without any functions its retriving 8 sec..

Answer (score 0):

Find the pain....

Delete the group by, delete the columns and focus on the join. You join is about unique_id AND summ_id AND modified_date, so I need an index with those three fields. The most discriminant field first, that's probably uniqueid / unique_id.

To help you focus on the join only write the result of the join in a temp table, like:

```
 select uniqueid 
 into #temp
 from ...
```

Do that if the join spits out 100k records you don't get confronted with side effects (like for example sending all those records to you management studio).

Comment: Hi Paul , checked for your request as well but create temp taking 15 sec and select process 15 sec totally 30 more sec taking for this process..this is better idea but its take so time..